# Find the value of $a$ and $b$, so the linear system stays consistant

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering if someone could take a look at my solution and tell me if i'm wrong. I feel like my solution is incorrect.

Given
$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&1&2&2a-b+1\\
  2&1&1&3a-b+1\\
  1&2&5&3a-2b+6
\end{array}
\right] $ find the values of a and b so the system stays consistent.

I tried to put the system into RREF. So, the first thing I did was R1-R2

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  -1&0&1&-a\\
  2&1&1&3a-b+1\\
  1&2&5&3a-2b+6
\end{array}
\right] $$
R2-2R1
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  -1&0&1&-a\\
  0&1&3&a-b+1\\
  1&2&5&3a-2b+6
\end{array}
\right] $$
R3+R1
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  -1&0&1&-a\\
  0&1&3&a-b+1\\
  0&2&6&2a-2b+6
\end{array}
\right] $$
R3-2R2
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  -1&0&1&-a\\
  0&1&3&a-b+1\\
  0&0&0&-a-4b+6
\end{array}
\right] $$
Lastly, -R1
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&0&-1&a\\
  0&1&3&a-b+1\\
  0&0&0&-a-4b+6
\end{array}
\right] $$
The last equations gives $0=-a-4b+6$. This means that $a$ and $b$ can be any values as long as it follows that equation.

Comment: In the step you performed $R_3-2R_2$, the last entry in the right most column should be $4$. Thus you will get $0=4$. Hence inconsistent.

Comment: Since the pivot is $-1$ because of your first row operation (although why you did that is beyond me), your second operation is actually $R_2+2R_1$ instead of what you’ve written here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying the first equation by-2 and adding to the second we get

$$-x_2-3x_3=-a+b-1$$

and the first by -1 and adding to the third
$$x_2+3x_3=a-b+5$$
Can you finish?

Comment: if i multiply the first equation by -$1$ then I'm left with $x_2+3x_3 = a-b+1$. If I let the two equations equations equal each other i end up with 0=4. I'm not sure on what to do next.

Comment: This is a contradiction and the system has no solutions.